# How to have the log file in local using logback in spark streaming application running in yarn

Tags: logging, apache-spark, spark-streaming, logback, slf4j

the logs are not getting created in the file mentioned below but they are printing in the console when the application is runnning. please help me in the settings iam new to spark and logging concept.the path given below is in the server in which iam running the application.thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/media/Share-Temp-Folder/vivek/myLogFile.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
         <prudent>false</prudent><!-- true if multiple JVM's write to single file -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder
    </appender>
<root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How does your application use logback? Spark does not.

Comment: sorry,might be i misled you....actually i want to use logback to log  my scala application which run on spark......i just want to have the application logs separately in a file.can you please help me how can i do that?

Comment: Did you get any info about how to do this?